# Install mongo db and start mongo service using WiX toolset installer

Tags: mongodb, wix

I am creating a .msi installer using WiX Toolset which will:-
1. Install mongo db on client machine by running its mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.4-signed.msi
2. Make directories for \data\db and \log and config file
3. Start mongo service as a Window service.

I am new to Wix. I was able to set it up and create a installer which is packaging mongo setup msi and config file to Wix installer. But it is just copying these files to install flocation. I want all the above steps to performed by WiX installer. Below are important section:-

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='EMERSONMONGO' Name="$(var.rootFolder)">
        <Directory Id='PFWMONGOFOLDER' Name='$(var.subRootFolder)'>
          <Directory Id='MONGO' Name='$(var.installFolder)'>
            <Component Id="mongodb.msi" Guid="99B82660-F66B-4012-B742-D875623B1C16">
                <File Id="mongodb.msi" Source="$(var.mongoSourceDir)\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.4-signed.msi" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

<Feature Id='Complete' Title='PFWMongo Installer' Description='PFWMongo Installer' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id="mongodb.msi" />
 </Feature>

<CustomAction Id="RunMongoMsi" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" 
                  FileKey="mongodb.msi" ExeCommand=""  
                  HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='RunMongoMsi' Before='InstallFinalize'/>
        <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" >
             UNINSTALLPREVVERSIONS
        </RemoveExistingProducts>
        <Custom Action="NewerVersion" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERVERSIONDETECTED</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use the [WiX Bootstrapper](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/)/[Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/) for this. You would then add the install to the chain similar to this.

`<Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="mongodb.msi" SourceFile="$(var.mongoSourceDir)\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.4-signed.msi" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="yes" Visible="yes" />
</Chain>`